# Почему страница выглядит больше, чем нужно?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть сайт, который при 100%(стандартное значение) масштабирования в браузере выглядит слишком большим [image: Масштаб 100%]

Но если я ставлю значение в браузере на 67%, то все выглядит как надо
[image: Масштаб 67%]

Comment: При необходимости могу прикрепить html и css код

Comment: "Больше чем нужно", а с чем вы сравнивали?

Comment: С сайтом на котором тренировался: https://usdd.network/#/
Не реклама

Comment: А значения брали оттуда же или писали самостоятельно?

Comment: оттуда же.
скинуть код?

Comment: Я посмотрел код того сайта, и думаю уже понял причину. Мне нужен ответ от вас, значения вы копировали с того же сайта или писали "на глаз" или "по линейке"?

Comment: Переписывал с этого же сайта

Comment: часть кода копировал, часть переписывал, но все сравнивал и проверял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание, что сайт из примера использует практически везде единицу измерения [`rem`](https://webref.ru/css/unit/rem), она зависит от элемента `html`, т.е. если в настройках браузера размер шрифта будет составлять 16px, то 1rem будет равен 16px.
Если же для `html` установить `font-size: 12px`, то `1rem` === `12px`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сайте примера, размер шрифта `html` устанавливается явно из JS по каким-то критериям.
И скорее всего ваш сайт выглядит больше, т.е. не учтён этот момент.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Не за что. Если мой ответ помог, отметьте его как правильный)